# Обратно строку в массив

Tags: javascript

У меня есть такая строка
`"[1,2,3,4,5,6]"`
могу ли я ее преобразовать обратно в массив помимо разделения по запятой?

Comment: Скорее JSON в массив, а строку можно и так `[..."строка"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let str = "[1,2,3,4,5,6]";
let arr = JSON.parse(str);
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
console.log(JSON.parse("[1,2,3,4,5,6]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно ещё воспользоваться функцией [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), только ненужно)

```js
let str = "[1,2,3,4,5,6]";
console.info(typeof eval(str));
console.info(eval(str))
```

```css
code {white-space: nowrap !important;}
```